# How to set value of checkbox in codeigniter and show checked state?

Tags: codeigniter, checkbox

I have a series of checkboxes in codeigniter and need to show the checked state and value when a form is submitted.

How can I do this?? I have read the documentation of the codeigniter website but cannot see how to set the checked state?

This is my code:

```
<?php echo form_checkbox('spa', 'y', FALSE, '') ?>
```

Comment: where you want to show the checked values ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
echo form_checkbox('spa', 'y', TRUE); //TRUE sets it as checked
```

See: **form_checkbox()** in codeigniter [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Answer (score 5):

To repopulate a checkbox after an unsuccessful form validation use this:

```
form_checkbox('my_option', 'value', set_checkbox('my_option', 'value'));
```