# Show checked checkbox base recursive ID in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wanna create a checked checkbox base id in recursive table, I have table like this

```
+---------+--------------+-----------+
|user_id  | function_id  | feature_id|
+---------+--------------+-----------+
| 1       |  2           |  1        |
+---------+--------------+-----------+
| 1       |  2           |  2        |
+---------+--------------+-----------+
| 1       |  2           |  3        |
+---------+--------------+-----------+
```

and then the checked box using foreach

```
$feature = $this->db->get_where('my_table', array('function_id' => '2'))->result();
foreach ($result as $value)
{
$data = array(
        'name'          => 'feature_id',
        'value'         => $value->feature_id,
        'checked'       => // depend on feature_id if in function_id the feature id is exist then checked TRUE else FALSE
);

echo form_checkbox($data);
```

Plz help me! :(

Comment: may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878986/how-to-set-value-of-checkbox-in-codeigniter-and-show-checked-state

Comment: @yulianto can you please check my answer and let me know, if it's working for you or not?

Answer (score 1):

Change your php code like this and let me know.

```
$feature = $this->db->get_where('my_table', array('function_id' => '2'))->result();

foreach ($result as $value) {

    $state = (!empty($value->feature_id)) ? TRUE : FALSE;

    $data = array( 'name' => 'feature_id',
                   'value' => $value->feature_id,
                   'checked' => $state);

    echo form_checkbox($data);
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to display all your `checkboxs` then it must be inside your `foreach` loop.

Comment: It doesn't work sir, I have another question it's is the simple one, but I still don't know the answer LOL,
for example suppose, I have a data like in a table 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 then I loop the data, using foreach, and I want to choose 2, 3, and 5 in checkbox, how to create like that? Please help me!!

Comment: Need more information here. Is rows in your table are limited? or there are n number of rows? In short number of checkboxs are limited?